# how to add attribute to symfony form collectionType element

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, attributes

My form in php:

```
class MyType extends AbstractType 
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
     ->add('configFiles', CollectionType::class, array(
       'entry_type' => TextareaType::class,
       'allow_add' => true,
       'allow_delete' => true,
       'by_reference' => false,
       'prototype' => true
    ))      
  }
  ...
}
```

My form in twig:

```
...
<div class="form-group">
  {{ form_label(create_lab_form.configFiles) }}
  <div class="configFiles" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(create_lab_form.configFiles.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
  </div>
  {{ form_errors(create_lab_form.configFiles) }}
  </div>
  {% do create_lab_form.configFiles.setRendered %}
</div>
...
```

How to add attribute (e.g. "rows") for Textarea collection element in example above?

I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
->add('configFiles', CollectionType::class, array(
   'entry_type' => TextareaType::class, array(
      'attr' => array('rows' => 10
   )),
   'allow_add' => true,
   'allow_delete' => true,
   'by_reference' => false,
   'prototype' => true
 ))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is right but you are using the wrong key:

```
'entry_type' => TextareaType::class,
'entry_options'  => array(
  'attr' => array(
      'rows' => 10
  )),
```

should do the yob